# How to call a riverpod provider outside of widget tree/widget class?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am new to using RiverPod. previously I used Provider for state management.

in case of provider I could use a provider outside widget tree to get value using syntax

```
Provider.of<MyModel>(context,listen:true).someFunction();
```

how do I do the same in RiverPod? for now I am using Consumer Builder and Consumer Widget. I was wondering if there's a way to call a riverpod provider without using Consumer.

Comment: Have you tried? ```ref.read(theProvider).someFunction();```

Comment: @Josteve What do I assign to final Ref ref? to use this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily call `riverpord` provider without using `Consumer`. Please check out my below extension which is very helpful to call the provider based on context where it will work for the read function without any consumer or consumer widget.

```dart
extension Context on BuildContext {
  // Custom call a provider for reading method only
  // It will be helpful for us for calling the read function
  // without Consumer,ConsumerWidget or ConsumerStatefulWidget
  // Incase if you face any issue using this then please wrap your widget
  // with consumer and then call your provider

  T read<T>(ProviderBase<T> provider) {
     return ProviderScope.containerOf(this, listen: false).read(provider);
  }
}
```

After then under the build method, you must call context.read(yourProviderName)

Answer (score 2):

let's say you have a separate class that is responsible for ui logic:

```dart
class UiController {
  UiController(this._ref);

  final Ref _ref;

  Reader get _reader => _ref.read;

  static final pr = Provider<UiController>((ref) => UiController(ref));

  void someFunction() {
    _reader(otherProvider).getValue();
  }
}
```

from a widget or other functions where ref is accessed, you can call:

```dart
ref.read(UiController.pr).someFunction();
```

Comment: can't ref.read(UiController.pr).someFunction(); be called somewhere outside a widget class?

Comment: only if we have access to ref. Otherwise, you can try using [UncontrolledProviderScope](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/295#issuecomment-770368500)